# Prusa i3 MK8 can't achieve required temperature

Tags: prusa-i3, hotend, temperature

I've just installed a new 12 V hotend for my Prusa i3 MK8. So, now the new hotend can't achieve temperatures above 190-200 °C and it takes about 30 minutes to achieve 200 °C. The thermistor and heating element both touch the hotend securely. The heating element gets 12 V all the time. PID changes don't seem to affect anything. Can it be fixed or do I have to change the hotend?

Comment: If the MK8 is a typographical error and should be MK3. Prusa MK3 printers are 24v. Confusing the issue is that you've noted you measured 12v (?) which implies it's a different model than a MK3.

Comment: Have you installed a 24V heater cartridge into a 12V printer? That will turn a 40W heater into a 10W heater,